# Smallest part in Partition in Quick Sort with some conditions?

Tags: sorting, math, probability, quicksort, partitioning

Let `0 < a < 0.5` be some constant. We have an `n-element` array as input. Randomized quicksort chooses one element from array uniformly at random as a pivot and partitions. With which probability the smallest section be greater than `an`. my short answer in note say with probability `1-2a`. anyone could say how this probability calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the smaller partition is evenly distributed in the range [0, n/2], so the probability that it will be smaller than `an` is `an / (n/2)`. So the probability that it will be larger than `a` is `1 - an / (n/2)`. `an/(n/2)` is precisely `2a`, hence the probability `1 - 2a`.

Here's a diagram, in case it helps:

```
                     Pivot positions

                a·n    n/2            a·n+n/2   n 
                 v      v                v      v
<---------------------|||||||·---------------------|||||||>
                     /---^---\                    /---^---\
              smaller partition on left   smaller partition on right
                   bigger than a·n              bigger than a·n
                   size: n/2 - a·n           size: n - (a·n + n/2)
                             Total size: n - 2a·n
                              Probability: 1 - 2a
```

Comment: Really I couldn't get it. is it possible more explain?

Comment: @mio: if i select a random number between 0 and 100, what is the probability that it less than 20? That it is greater than 20? What if the range was 0 to 50? It is no different.

Comment: I think A random pivot has the same distribution as x_i for i chosen uniformly at random from {1,…,n}. The size of the smaller partition is min(i−1,n−i). If I is the set of indices i such that min(i−1,n−i)≥an, then the probability is | I | / n. but  cannot continue from here...

Comment: @mio:consider the two possibilities independently. If the first partition is smaller (`i <= n/2`), the probability that it is bigger than `an` is `1 - an/(n/2)`. Exactly the same if the second partition is smaller. And those two possibilities have the same probability: half the time its the first partition, half the time the second.

Comment: @mio: in other words, the size of the smaller partition is evenly distributed over half the size of the original.

Comment: Sorry because of my lack knowledge, I confused. I accept it but please add more detail to your answer to best understand thanks,

Comment: Sorry is it possible to partition smaller and bigger than a·n at the same time?

Comment: @Mio: If you partition a list of n objects, you end up with two parts. One is bigger and the other is smaller. The bigger one must be bigger than n/2. So in the chart (which might be more confusing than helpful) the region on the left shows pivot choices where the first partition is smaller, and the region on the right shows pivot choices where the first partition is bigger.

Comment: so text on figure has error. because on each part you wrote smaller and bigger...

Comment: @mio: The partition is smaller (than the other part) and bigger than a.n

Comment: I'm so sorry for my lack of knowledge, would you please explain more ? we have two valid section first smaller than an? or bigger than an? what is other part ?

Comment: @mio: probably this is a language issue. Think: What does the partition operation do? (If you don't know, look at wikipedia in your language.) Or maybe I should just delete the diagram, which is obviously not helping.